# react router multiple goBack

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, browser-history, react-router-dom

I have a react app with react-router. I have multiple routes, and some of them are shown in a modal window. If I close the modal, I want to send back the user to the previous page, where modal was not active yet.

To know, if I have modal open, I use the state `modal:true` on the location. I know I could use simply history.goBack(), but I have the scenario when I'm on `/login` and the user goes from there to `/register`, but both routes show a modal. In this case, if the user clicks the close button on the modal, they will go back first to `/login`.

I tried to do something like this, but the `history` object is not updated with the new state.

```js
goBack = () => {
  while(true) {
   history.goBack();
   if (!history.location.state || !history.location.state.modal) {
     break;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you using hash history? The README states that it is only "supported in `createBrowserHistory` and `createMemoryHistory`".

Comment: I'm using browser history